# This bundle is invalid . New app and app updates submitted to the app store must be build with xcode 5 and ios 7 sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, app-store

I'm not Able to post Application with Xcode 4.6.2, while uploading it is giving me error. It gets rejected due to what seems like a sdk error:

Error delivering iOS App update.

```
“This bundle is invalid. New apps and updates submitted to the App store must be built with Xcode 5 and ios 7 SDK.”
```

[image]

I'm struggling to figure out what has changed since I am building with the same SDK as I did last weekend.

Comment: Can you read? it says **"New apps and updates submitted to the App store must be built with Xcode 5 and ios 7 SDK."** Also look at [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a).

Comment: From 1st February it's mandatory to use Xcode 5

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app submisions

Comment: The date has changed since last week. It's now February 2014. See Apples News and Announcements: ["Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7."](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a). You should have received an email about this as well.

Comment: "I'm using Xcode 4.6.2. The error tells me I should be using version 5. What on Earth could be the problem???". Seriously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting February 1, 2014, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

From February 2014, apps that are built with iOS 7 SDK only will be approved by the app store. And for iOS 7, as you know, you must use Xcode 5.